# how to change bg color of button after pressing and get back to previous color

Tags: python, button, tkinter, widget

In the below program i want to change the background color of the button to green after pressing it and changed color should remain for 2seconds and later change back to original color. Is there a way to do?

```
import tkinter as tk
class MyGui(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyGui, self).__init__()
        self.create_widgets()

    def widget_button(self):
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.buttonA = tk.Button(self.frame, padx=13, pady=6, bd=4, text="Sample",bg="black", command=self.trial)

    def trial(self):
        print("Button color is changed to green")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = MyGui()
    root.mainloop()
```

In the program the default color is black now i want to change to green for 2secs after pressing

Comment: I would like just to make you notice that if you are on a Mac OS X, you might not be able to change the background color of your buttons, apart also from the fact that usually you cannot change their height. If you really need a button with a custom color, you could use a Label as a button and bind to it the necessary events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `after` method to schedule a function to run after a pre-defined amount of time. You can use the `configure` method to change a widget option. Put those two together and you have something like this:

```
def trial(self):
    self.buttonA.configure(background="green")
    self.after(2000, lambda: self.buttonA.configure(background="black")
```

Answer (score 0):

it works fine if i put code like:

```
def trial(self):
    self.buttonA.configure(background="green")
    self.after(10, lambda: self.buttonA.configure(background="black")
    self.after(2000, lambda: self.buttonA.configure(background="green")
```

But am not sure whether its correct way or not